# SourceTree thinks develop branch is a feature

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am running SourceTree 3.1.3 on Windows 10.  For some reason it has started thinking that my `develop` branch is a `Feature` branch.  I can't create new features and am doubtful of "ending" the develop branch just to try creating a new one.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Open main folder of your project, enable Hidden items (under View options of Windows folder) then go to .git folder and open 'config' file and make sure that your gitflow prefixes look like this:

```
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    bugfix = bugfix/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag =
```

Restart Sourcetree and it should work.

Comment: Ah!  I will try this the next time it happens.  I "fixed" my problem by deleting the remote git repo and the local `.git` dir.  Then I initialized a new git instance and created a new remote repo.  It's working now but I'm glad it was a new-ish project and didn't actually lose much history